# How to find keywords from mysql using stored procedure. I am using php but it takes too much time

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, keyword

I have a database in mysql and 20K Records in it. I want to find out keywords from '**text**' field of table which occurred more than two times in any sentence. I don't want to compare whole sentence of '**text**' field. I need to compare each and every word of a sentence with all the data of 'text' field. I did this in Php but It is taking too much time, so need code for same in stored procedure.

Query:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_tbl"); 
$text_tw=''; 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    { $text_tw .= $row['text']." "; } 
 echo extract_keywords($text_tw);
```

Function extract_keywords:

```
function extract_keywords($str)
  { ... 
    $healthy = array("\""); 
    $words = explode(' ', strtolower(trim(str_replace($healthy," ",$str)))); 
    $keywords = array(); 
    while(($c_word = array_shift($words)) !== null)
        {
         if (strpos($c_word,'@') === false AND strpos($c_word,'http') === false AND strlen($c_word) > 2)
         { 
           if(array_key_exists($c_word, $keywords)) 
                $keywords[$c_word][1]++; 
           else $keywords[$c_word] = array($c_word, 1); 
          } 
         } 
     ... 
     foreach($keywords as $keyword_det) 
        { 
           if($keyword_det[1] < 10) break; 
           array_push($final_keywords, $keyword_det[0]); 
         } 
     return implode(', ', $final_keywords); 
   }
```

Thank You.

Comment: What does your query look like so far?

Comment: You are better off making a keyword table instead of searching every time

Comment: $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `my_tbl`");
$text_tw='';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $text_tw .= $row['text']." ";
}
echo extract_keywords($text_tw);

Comment: function extract_keywords($str){
 ...
 $healthy = array("\"");
 $words = explode(' ', strtolower(trim(str_replace($healthy," ",$str))));
 $keywords = array();
 while(($c_word = array_shift($words)) !== null){
  if (strpos($c_word,'@') === false AND strpos($c_word,'http') === false AND strlen($c_word) > 2){
   if(array_key_exists($c_word, $keywords)) $keywords[$c_word][1]++;
   else $keywords[$c_word] = array($c_word, 1);
  }
 }
 ...
 foreach($keywords as $keyword_det){
  if($keyword_det[1] < 10) break;
  array_push($final_keywords, $keyword_det[0]);
 }
 return implode(', ', $final_keywords);
}